# Python Command Prompt

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, cmd, command-prompt

I have both python 3 as well as python 2 version installed in my Windows PC. On calling variable name 'py' in cmd, python2.7 shows up even though I have mentioned python34 folder path in local environment PATH values. Please recommend a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by setting the  environment variable

```
SET PY_PYTHON=3
```

or by editing the py.ini in your applications data folder and adding the following line:

```
[defaults]
python=3
```

Typically, your application directory is found in `C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Application Data` or `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\` depending on the Windows version.

Comment: I just added the path to system variable. Its working. However thanks :-)